# htmlunit cannot process javascript module

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit, rhino

When parsing a complex web page with HTMLUnit, with javascript enabled, it refuses to process type="module" scripts.

Looking at the source code of HTMLUnit HtmlScript it looks like scripts of any type other than *"text/javascript" || « text/ecmascript » or « application/javascript" || « application/ecmascript" || "application/x-javascript"* are rejected

Error is: 
*com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript isExecutionNeeded
WARNING: Script is not JavaScript (type: module, language: ). Skipping execution.*

Is there a way to have module scripts also executed ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. You could switch to Chrome/Firefox/Another browser. Or if you just want to supress that error use `client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);`

Comment: Please file a bug report for HtmlUnit or even better provide a patch (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will asap file a request. Not sure I have the skills and time though to contribute to a patch

Comment: done : https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/1 Although I'm quite scared when I notice this is the only issue on this github...

Comment: moved bug report to sourceforge (i should have read http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html before : shame on me). See here : https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1990/. Thanks again for your feedback

Comment: @Hadriensz Were you able to get a workaround for this issue? I am currently having the same challenge